# Server compromised or hacked

Tags: linux, ubuntu, subdomain, hacking

I don't understand how this subdomain appeared today: http://hainanbank.com.cn.croppio.com/.

I have only added https://croppio.com/ without any sub-domains.

I double checked the server configuration and the virtual hosts, they are as expected.

I checked the ssh logins with `last` but there is no suspicious activity and I also changed my ssh user password.

Has somebody hacked and added the sub-domain, what I need to do in order to find and remove the sub-domain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wildcard entry for `*.croppio.com`, which returns a `CNAME` to `croppio.com`. Maybe you did add it, but you forgot about it?

Comment: Yes, I have this record: Type/Name/Data/TTL -> CNAME / * / croppio.com / 300. I never added that sub-domain.

Comment: I tried clownworld.croppio.com and it loaded.

Comment: Did you start with an empty DNS zone or a template from your DNS provider? Maybe they have it in the default zone.

Comment: I started with a template from my DNS provider. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just delete the record. And good news: probably the DNS was not hacked, you just never noticed that record.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has added the CNAME entry for `hainanbank.com.cn.croppio.com`. The CNAME entry points to `croppio.com`.

You need to check with your DNS provider how the CNAME was added.